# Packing vertex data into a WebGL texture

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, shader, textures

I am trying to store a vertex array in a WebGL texture but can't really figure out how to do it correctly.
The purpose of this is to pass the vertices to my fragment shader and process them for raytracing.

My JavaScript code looks currently like this:

```
var a = new ArrayBuffer();
// Model.VerticeMap is an array holding all vertices [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ...]
a = Model.VerticeMap;  // array length: 36864
var dataArray = new Float32Array(a);
var vMapTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, vMapTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, dataArray);
```

I get no errors with a texture width and height of 2. Taking higher values results in the error `ArrayBufferView not big enough for request`.

I am also using the extension `OES_texture_float` for float values in textures.

I must admit that I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing there. It was more of a back and forth and I was kind of happy when I got to the point of not getting any errors with this code. My main thought was to store the x,y,z values of every vertex as r,g,b values of every pixel of the texture. Therefore the texture size would have to be equal with or higher than the number of triangles of my 3D model. Unfortunately, texture sizes in WebGL are limited to power of two numbers. The number of vertices should also be variable, since I'm planning to render multiple models in my scene.

I would be grateful for some assistance concerning the correct usage of an `ArrayBuffer`, a `Float32Array` and the `texImage2D()` command to solve my problem of sending vertices to a fragment shader in WebGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution for my problem:

First we need to calculate a fitting texture width

```
var vMapTexture = gl.createTexture();
var vertexTextureWidth = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(verticeCount/3));
```

With `verticeCount` being the length of our vertex array, we divide it by 3 to fit it in the RGB components of a pixel, take the squareroot of it and round it up to make sure that all our vertices fit in the texture. The texture width is also equal with the texture height.

Next, we create a Float32Array

```
var a = new Float32Array(vertexTextureWidth * vertexTextureWidth * 3);
```

I fill it with the values from my vertex array

```
for(var i = 0; i < (verticeCount); i++){
a[i] = Model.VerticeMap[i];
}
```

Now set your texture to be active and bind it:

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, vMapTexture);
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "uVertexTexture"), 1);
```

To pack the data into the texture, I use the following line

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, vertexTextureWidth, vertexTextureWidth, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, a);
```

I use the `RGB` format an the `FLOAT` type. In order to do this, you have to enable the `OES_texture_float` extension.

Finally, add the following texture parameters:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

The resulting texture now contains my vertex array and looks like this

[image: RGB Vertex Texture]

I'm open for comments or remarks to this solution, feel free to contribute with code simplifications or other approaches.

Answer (score -3):

If you're not fond of buffers then you should start at [Learning WebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217) (where everyone else does).

Textures are a bad idea to store vertex data because each color value only stores one Byte and you surely want at least some float32 for your vertices. And your attempt goes for shader attributes and point-plotting anyway.